# Не работает плавное изменение графики TweenMax при переключении между сценами

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, slider, css-animation, gsap

У меня проблема с настройкой TweenMax (TweenLite) под не совсем нормальную задачу.
Требуется сделать шесть слайдов анимации. Проблема в том, что **вся анимация должна происходить внутри одного окна и с одними и теми же элементами. 
Каждая сцена должна инициироваться событием скролла или кликом на стрелки вперед назад.**
Использую технологии tweenmax, tweenlite, greensock, gsap
В сети нашла приблизительный пример https://codepen.io/mikeK/pen/vJNRPQ

```js
  //  =============  xxxxx  ========================== 

  TweenMax.set(".centered, nav", {autoAlpha: 1, xPercent:-50, yPercent:-50, force3D:true}); 


  //Forked from [Chrysto](http://codepen.io/bassta/)'s Pen [Fullscreen slides with TweenLite, CSSPlugin and ScrollToPlugin](http://codepen.io/bassta/pen/kDvmC/).  Optimized with the help of Blake Owen

  //First the variables our app is going to use need to be declared

  //References to DOM elements
  var $window = $(window);
  var $document = $(document);
  //Only links that starts with #
  var $navButtons = $("nav a").filter("[href^=#]");
  var $navGoPrev = $(".go-prev");
  var $navGoNext = $(".go-next");
  var $slidesContainer = $(".slides-container");
  var $allSlides = $(".slide");
  var $currentSlide = $allSlides.first();
  var slideControl = $("nav a")


  //Animating flag - is our app animating
  var isAnimating = false;

  //The height of the window
  var pageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

  //Key codes for up and down arrows on keyboard. We'll be using this to navigate change slides using the keyboard
  var keyCodes = {
    UP  : 38,
    DOWN: 40
  };


  var currentIndex = 0;
  
  var timeline1 = new TimelineLite()

 .reverse();
 
 
  var timeline2 = new TimelineLite()
    .to("#hand01", 0.5,{autoAlpha:1, repeat:3}, "+=0.5")  
    .to("#mund01", 0.5,{morphSVG:"#mund02"}, "+=0")
    .to("#kopf, #mund01", 1, {autoAlpha: 0}, "+=1")
    .to("#kopf02, #mund03", 1, {autoAlpha: 1}, "-=1")
    .to("#text", 1, {autoAlpha: 1}, "-=0.5")
    .to("#kamera", 1, {rotation:-20, transformOrigin:"50% 50%"}, "-=0.5")
    .to('.againPIN', 0.5, {autoAlpha: 1},"+=1")    
    .reverse();

 $(".againPIN").on("click", function() {
  timeline2.restart();
 }); 
 
  
  var timeline3 = new TimelineLite({repeat:-1, yoyo: true,  repeatDelay:0.5})
    .to("#ME",2, {morphSVG:"#ME02", repeat:3, yoyo: true,  repeatDelay:0.5})
    .fromTo("#YOU",2, {y:"+110%"}, {y:"0%", repeat:3, yoyo: true,  repeatDelay:0.5},0.2)
    .to('.againME', 0.5, {autoAlpha: 1},"+=1") 
    .reverse();
 
 $(".againME").on("click", function() {
  timeline3.restart();
 }); 

 
 var timeline4 = new TimelineLite()
 .set('.sonne', {autoAlpha: 1})
 .fromTo('.sonne', 4, {x:"-150%"}, {x:"+200%", scale: 0.4, ease: Power4.easeNone},0)
 .to('.sonne', 0.1, {autoAlpha: 0},"-=1")
 .to('#wolke', 4, {x:"+80%", ease: Power4.easeNone},"-=1")
 .to(".rohr01",0.07, {x:"-30px", repeat:9,  yoyo: true, repeatDelay:0.1, ease: Power4.easeIn},0.8)
 .to('.againGreenAttack', 0.5, {autoAlpha: 1},"+=1") 
    .reverse();

 $(".againGreenAttack").on("click", function() {
  timeline4.restart();
 }); 
 
  var timeline5 = new TimelineLite()
    .set('.rauch', { autoAlpha:1}, "+=1")
    .to('.rauch', 3, { y: "-100%", scale:1.8, opacity:0, repeat: 3, repeatDelay: 1})
    .to('.againHELMUT', 0.5, {autoAlpha: 1},"+=1")
    .reverse();

 $(".againHELMUT").on("click", function() {
  timeline5.restart();
 });  
 
  var timelines = [timeline1, timeline2, timeline3, timeline4, timeline5];
  
  //Going to the first slide
  goToSlide($currentSlide);
  //TweenLite.set($currentSlide, {className: "+=active"});

  /*
 *   Adding event listeners
 * */

 $window.on("resize", onResize).resize();
 $window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", onMouseWheel);
 $document.on("keydown", onKeyDown);
 $navButtons.on("click", onNavButtonClick);
 $navGoPrev.on("click", goToPrevSlide);
 $navGoNext.on("click", goToNextSlide);
 
  
  /*
 *   Internal functions
 * */


  /*
 *   When a button is clicked - first get the button href, and then slide to the container, if there's such a container
 * */
  function onNavButtonClick(event)
  {
    //The clicked button
    var $button = $(this);

    //The slide the button points to
    var $slide = $($button.attr("href"));

    //If the slide exists, we go to it
    if($slide.length)
    {
      goToSlide($slide);
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  /*
 *   Getting the pressed key. Only if it's up or down arrow, we go to prev or next slide and prevent default behaviour
 *   This way, if there's text input, the user is still able to fill it
 * */
  function onKeyDown(event)
  {

    var PRESSED_KEY = event.keyCode;

    if(PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.UP)
    {
      goToPrevSlide();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    else if(PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.DOWN)
    {
      goToNextSlide();
      event.preventDefault();
    }

  }

  /*
 *   When user scrolls with the mouse, we have to change slides
 * */
  function onMouseWheel(event)
  {
    //Normalize event wheel delta
    var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 30 || -event.originalEvent.detail;

    //If the user scrolled up, it goes to previous slide, otherwise - to next slide
    if(delta < -1)
    {
      goToNextSlide();
    }
    else if(delta > 1)
    {
      goToPrevSlide();
    }

    event.preventDefault();


  }

  /*
 *   If there's a previous slide, slide to it
 * */
  function goToPrevSlide()
  {
    if($currentSlide.prev().length)
    {
      goToSlide($currentSlide.prev());
    }
  }

  /*
 *   If there's a next slide, slide to it
 * */
  function goToNextSlide()
  {
    if($currentSlide.next().length)
    {
      goToSlide($currentSlide.next());
    }
  }


  /*
 *   Actual transition between slides
 * */
  function goToSlide($slide)
  {
    //If the slides are not changing and there's such a slide
    if(!isAnimating && $slide.length)
    {
      //setting animating flag to true
      isAnimating = true;
      $currentSlide = $slide;
      NextSlide = $currentSlide.next()           

      //Sliding to current slide
      TweenLite.to($slidesContainer, 1, {scrollTo: {y: pageHeight * $currentSlide.index() }, onComplete: onSlideChangeEnd, onCompleteScope: this});

      //Definig slide status
      TweenLite.to($allSlides.filter(".active"), 0.1, {className: "-=active"});
      TweenLite.to($allSlides.filter($currentSlide), 0.1, {className: "+=active"});

      //Animating menu items
      TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter(".active"), 0.5, {className: "-=active"});
      TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter("[href=#" + $currentSlide.attr("id") + "]"), 0.5, {className: "+=active"});


    }
  }

  /*
 *   Once the sliding is finished, we need to restore "isAnimating" flag.
 *   You can also do other things in this function, such as changing page title
 * */
  function onSlideChangeEnd() {
    isAnimating = false;
    
    // Reverse the timeline for the previous slide
    timelines[currentIndex].reversed(true).progress(0);
    
    // Change the index
    currentIndex = $currentSlide.index();
    
    // Play the timeline for the current slide
    timelines[currentIndex].reversed(false);
  }

  /*
 *   When user resize it's browser we need to know the new height, so we can properly align the current slide
 * */
  function onResize(event)
  {

    //This will give us the new height of the window
    var newPageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

    /*
  *   If the new height is different from the old height ( the browser is resized vertically ), the slides are resized
  * */
    if(pageHeight !== newPageHeight)
    {
      pageHeight = newPageHeight;

      //This can be done via CSS only, but fails into some old browsers, so I prefer to set height via JS
      TweenLite.set([$slidesContainer, $allSlides], {height: pageHeight + "px"});

      //The current slide should be always on the top
      TweenLite.set($slidesContainer, {scrollTo: {y: pageHeight * $currentSlide.index() }});
    }

  }
```

Но здесь слайды сменяются и в разных сценах обрабатываются разные элементы.
Вот здесь попробовала схематично изобразить, что мне необходимо: https://codepen.io/yuliarushay/pen/PBjeyN
Приблизительно работает как требуется - внутри одного окна, сменяется по клику и по скроллу. НО главная **проблема - нет плавного перехода от одного состояния элемента к второму состоянию и далее к третьему. Анимация как бы скачет при запуске каждой последующей сцены.** 
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!
*p.s. это для меня неизведанная область, поэтому не могу объяснить почему, но по ссылке в codepen сам розовый элемент, с которым должны происходить трансформации, появляется только если передвинуть вверх вниз разделитель экранов (простите).*

```js
//  =============  xxxxx  ==========================

TweenMax.set(".centered, nav", {
  autoAlpha: 1,
  xPercent: -50,
  yPercent: -50,
  force3D: true
});


//Forked from [Chrysto](http://codepen.io/bassta/)'s Pen [Fullscreen slides with TweenLite, CSSPlugin and ScrollToPlugin](http://codepen.io/bassta/pen/kDvmC/).  Optimized with the help of Blake Owen

//First the variables our app is going to use need to be declared

//References to DOM elements
var $window = $(window);
var $document = $(document);
//Only links that starts with #
var $navButtons = $("nav a").filter("[href^=#]");
var $navGoPrev = $(".go-prev");
var $navGoNext = $(".go-next");
var $slidesContainer = $(".slides-container");
var $allSlides = $(".slide");
var $currentSlide = $allSlides.first();
var slideControl = $("nav a")


//Animating flag - is our app animating
var isAnimating = false;

//The height of the window
var pageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

//Key codes for up and down arrows on keyboard. We'll be using this to navigate change slides using the keyboard
var keyCodes = {
  UP: 38,
  DOWN: 40
};


var currentIndex = 0;

var timeline1 = new TimelineLite()
  .to('.eqz', 1, {
    x: "+80%",
    ease: Power4.easeNone
  })
.reverse();


var timeline2 = new TimelineLite()
  .to('.eqz', 1, {
    x: "-80%",
    ease: Power4.easeNone
  }, "-=1")
  .to('.againPIN', 0.5, {
    autoAlpha: 1
  })
.reverse();

$(".againPIN").on("click", function() {
  timeline2.restart();
});


var timeline3 = new TimelineLite()
.to('.eqz', 1, {
  transform: "scale(3)",
  ease: Power4.easeNone
}, "-=1")
  .to('.againME', 0.5, {
    autoAlpha: 1
  }, "+=1")
.reverse();

$(".againME").on("click", function() {
  timeline3.restart();
});

var timeline4 = new TimelineLite()
.to('.eqz', 2, {
  transform: "scale(2)",
  ease: Power4.easeNone
}, "-=1")
  .to('.againGreenAttack', 0.5, {
    autoAlpha: 1
  }, "+=1")
.reverse();

$(".againGreenAttack").on("click", function() {
  timeline4.restart();
});

var timeline5 = new TimelineLite()
  .to('.againHELMUT', 0.5, {
    autoAlpha: 1
  }, "+=1")
.reverse();

$(".againHELMUT").on("click", function() {
  timeline5.restart();
});

var timelines = [timeline1, timeline2, timeline3, timeline4, timeline5];

//Going to the first slide
goToSlide($currentSlide);
//TweenLite.set($currentSlide, {className: "+=active"});

/*
 *   Adding event listeners
 * */

$window.on("resize", onResize).resize();
$window.on("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", onMouseWheel);
$document.on("keydown", onKeyDown);
$navButtons.on("click", onNavButtonClick);
$navGoPrev.on("click", goToPrevSlide);
$navGoNext.on("click", goToNextSlide);


/*
 *   Internal functions
 * */


/*
 *   When a button is clicked - first get the button href, and then slide to the container, if there's such a container
 * */
function onNavButtonClick(event) {
  //The clicked button
  var $button = $(this);

  //The slide the button points to
  var $slide = $($button.attr("href"));

  //If the slide exists, we go to it
  if ($slide.length) {
    goToSlide($slide);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

/*
 *   Getting the pressed key. Only if it's up or down arrow, we go to prev or next slide and prevent default behaviour
 *   This way, if there's text input, the user is still able to fill it
 * */
function onKeyDown(event) {

  var PRESSED_KEY = event.keyCode;

  if (PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.UP) {
    goToPrevSlide();
    event.preventDefault();
  } else if (PRESSED_KEY == keyCodes.DOWN) {
    goToNextSlide();
    event.preventDefault();
  }

}

/*
 *   When user scrolls with the mouse, we have to change slides
 * */
function onMouseWheel(event) {
  //Normalize event wheel delta
  var delta = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 30 || -event.originalEvent.detail;

  //If the user scrolled up, it goes to previous slide, otherwise - to next slide
  if (delta < -1) {
    goToNextSlide();
  } else if (delta > 1) {
    goToPrevSlide();
  }

  event.preventDefault();


}

/*
 *   If there's a previous slide, slide to it
 * */
function goToPrevSlide() {
  if ($currentSlide.prev().length) {
    goToSlide($currentSlide.prev());
  }
}

/*
 *   If there's a next slide, slide to it
 * */
function goToNextSlide() {
  if ($currentSlide.next().length) {
    goToSlide($currentSlide.next());
  }
}


/*
 *   Actual transition between slides
 * */
function goToSlide($slide) {
  //If the slides are not changing and there's such a slide
  if (!isAnimating && $slide.length) {
    //setting animating flag to true
    isAnimating = true;
    $currentSlide = $slide;
    NextSlide = $currentSlide.next()

    //Sliding to current slide
    TweenLite.to($slidesContainer, 1, {
      scrollTo: {
        y: pageHeight * $currentSlide.index()
      },
      onComplete: onSlideChangeEnd,
      onCompleteScope: this
    });

    //Definig slide status
    TweenLite.to($allSlides.filter(".active"), 0.1, {
      className: "-=active"
    });
    TweenLite.to($allSlides.filter($currentSlide), 0.1, {
      className: "+=active"
    });

    //Animating menu items
    TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter(".active"), 0.5, {
      className: "-=active"
    });
    TweenLite.to($navButtons.filter("[href=#" + $currentSlide.attr("id") + "]"), 0.5, {
      className: "+=active"
    });


  }
}

/*
 *   Once the sliding is finished, we need to restore "isAnimating" flag.
 *   You can also do other things in this function, such as changing page title
 * */
function onSlideChangeEnd() {
  isAnimating = false;

  // Reverse the timeline for the previous slide
  timelines[currentIndex].reversed(true).progress(0);

  // Change the index
  currentIndex = $currentSlide.index();

  // Play the timeline for the current slide
  timelines[currentIndex].reversed(false);
}

/*
 *   When user resize it's browser we need to know the new height, so we can properly align the current slide
 * */
function onResize(event) {

  //This will give us the new height of the window
  var newPageHeight = $window.innerHeight();

  /*
   *   If the new height is different from the old height ( the browser is resized vertically ), the slides are resized
   * */
  if (pageHeight !== newPageHeight) {
    pageHeight = newPageHeight;

    //This can be done via CSS only, but fails into some old browsers, so I prefer to set height via JS
    TweenLite.set([$slidesContainer, $allSlides], {
      height: pageHeight + "px"
    });

    //The current slide should be always on the top
    TweenLite.set($slidesContainer, {
      scrollTo: {
        y: pageHeight * $currentSlide.index()
      }
    });
  }

}
```

вся сцена вот так выглядит и происходит в реальности (кусок из):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На этом же экране по клику или скроллу поезд смещается, фокус уходит обратно за экран и так далее.

Comment: подскажу ...А может подключить сам gsap?

Comment: Там же уже ТвинМакс подключен, в него все входит

Comment: Я уже все сделала на сценах tweenmax и scrollmagic, но там анимация сцены происходит постепенно при скролле одной высоты экрана и потом уже, достигнув триггера, переключается на следующую сцену. А м не надо чтобы именно по одному короткому скроллу или клику запускалась сразу вся сцена

Comment: тут вам особо не подскажут  задавайте tweenmax вопросы на slack группе gsap там вам помогут только ссылку codepen не забывайте

Comment: да я в сам гринсок\твинмакс на форум написала, но они там спят что ли еще. не отвечют( Спасибо, попробую в слак еще

Comment: в слаке есть группа animation-at-work у них есть раздел gsap вот они всегда помогают

Comment: сейчас будет тупой вопрос :) а как в слаке ее найти и туда попасть. У меня  есть только рабочая группа и все. Я в слаке примерно как в js разбираюсь - никак почти)

Comment: пардон) нашла, добавилась, с пасибо!

Comment: Рад помочь :)))